# Delete only those, which have no Entry in first table corresponding to the second table

Tags: javascript, mongoose, schema

```
var productSchema = Schema({
product_code: String,
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: String,
category:{
    type:  String,
    ref: 'Product_Category'
},
umo: String,
threshold: {
    type:Number,
    default: 0
},
image: String,
isactive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
}
});

var product_categorySchema = Schema({
isactive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: String
});
```

I have these two schema I am deleting from category, but if I have data corresponding to that category in product table then that category should not be deleted. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look like something like this :

```
     // Function which delete the category behind the given _id
     async function deleteCategory(idCategory) {
        // check if there is a product related to the category
        const ret = await product_schema.findOne({
          category: idCategory,
        });

        // if there is, return an error
        if (ret) throw new Error('Cannot delete the category');

        // else do delete the category
        return product_category_schema.remove({
          _id: idCategory,
        });
      }
```

---

Also you have to know that :

```
category:{
    type:  String,
    ref: 'Product_Category'
},
```

is not the right way to setup a reference; it should be an `ObjectId` not a `String`

```
const {
  Schema,
} = mongoose;

category:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product_Category'
},
```

Comment: are you writing the function with in schema file or in the nodeJS side. Because have tried working within schema but it didn't helped

Comment: It's in node.js side

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please update "type" property of "category" field in product schema like this:

```
category:{
  type:  Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Category' // model name
}`
```

and declare model like this :

```
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema );
```

then use "distinct" query and "$nin" query-operator to delete category which are not referenced by product schema like this :

```
Product.find().distinct('category').then((data)=>{
   Category.deleteMany({_id: {$nin: data}}).then(del => {
       console.log("deleted",del)
   })
})
```